# How layouts UI in Android Landscape Application

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm beginner of Android development.
So , I want to make simple calculator on landscape display.
and input number via button.

First, I used Constraint Layout and GridLayout and layout EditText and buttons to be set number.

[image]

But, Buttons' size and positions  are strange.

[image]

I wanted to move buttons to center position, and scale appropriately.

The reason why I enclose button with FrameLayout is their background will be set image and preventing distorting the images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/input_apo">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="428dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.57" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            >

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            >

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </FrameLayout><FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout><FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout><FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout><FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout><FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    </GridLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How do I fix their positions and scales ? or are their alternatives?I'm sorry that it may be very basic question,I really waste time this topic.Any help glad to me.

Comment: Pick a button which you want to place in the center, like it would be 5 which should be in the center then align other buttons with respective to this button position using respective property like toStartOf or toEndOf or whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you Jack I made it following your advice and constraint view no longer need frame layout because It can transform flexible size. Main problem is that I mistake setting xml editor device not corresponding with my AVD ,so scale is collapsed.Any way I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dispose frame layout and it works fine.
This main problem is that incompatibility of target android devise with XML Editor and AVD cause that collapse layout.
And I make it more flexible layout with combination constraint layout and grid layout ,showing this link.

[Is this a bug at Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851352/is-this-a-bug-at-android-studio)